# How to get a variable return from from external PHP file

Tags: php

This is my explaination about this problems.

My structure

```
config.php
modules
--module1
----menu.php
--module2
----menu.php
```

So, each module contains a `menu.php` file that just returns an array.

Now from config.php, I want to get that array. How can I do that ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post the relevant code in that `config.php` file and also say _how_ those other files are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$menu1 = include_once 'modules/module1/menu.php';
$menu2 = include_once 'modules/module2/menu.php';
```

Comment: Thank you, It's answer, I do not know the include function will return value.  I'll accept your answer in minutes

Comment: in your menu.php just make it like `return array(......);` It will include the content from menu.php to the variables.